# FastCGI with Ada

Tags: c, fastcgi, ada, mod-fcgid, mod-fastcgi

I found http://support.zeus.com/zws/examples/2005/12/16/hello_world_in_perl_and_c and this two examples are working.

Now I tried this for Ada and I can not get it done since 2 days.

**fcgi_stdio.ads**

```
with Interfaces.C;
with Interfaces.C.Strings;

package fcgi_stdio is
    function FCGI_Accept return Interfaces.C.int;
    pragma Import (C, FCGI_Accept, "FCGI_Accept");

    procedure FCGI_printf (str : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr);
    pragma Import (C, FCGI_printf, "FCGI_printf");
end fcgi_stdio;
```

**test.adb**

```
with fcgi_stdio;
with Interfaces.C;
with Interfaces.C.Strings;

procedure Test is
begin
    while Integer (fcgi_stdio.FCGI_Accept) >= 0 loop
        fcgi_stdio.FCGI_printf (Interfaces.C.Strings.New_String ("Content-Type: text/plain" & ASCII.LF & ASCII.LF));
        fcgi_stdio.FCGI_printf (Interfaces.C.Strings.New_String ("Hello World from Ada!" & ASCII.LF));
    end loop;
end Test;
```

When I run it in the console, I get following error:

```
$ ./test
raised STORAGE_ERROR : stack overflow or erroneous memory access
```

Apache error_log shows:

```
Premature end of script headers: test
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get it working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Experimenting on Mac OS X, it seems that the problem is that `FCGI_printf()` is a varargs function. It calls `FCGI_fprintf()`, also varargs:

```
int FCGI_fprintf(FCGI_FILE *fp, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int n = 0;
    va_start(ap, format);          <------ crash here
```

Ada doesn't have a standard way of specifying varargs functions, and GNAT doesn't have an implementation-defined way either.

The [GNAT documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Calling-Conventions.html#index-C-63) says that the solution is to provide a C wrapper for the varargs function:

```
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>
int FCGI_printf_wrapper(const char *msg)
{
  return FCGI_printf(msg);
}
```

and import the wrapper:

```
procedure FCGI_printf (str : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr);
pragma Import (C, FCGI_printf, "FCGI_printf_wrapper");
```

Another problem with the program is that in Ada, unlike C and many other languages, `"\n"` is not a way of inserting a newline character in a string. Try

```
fcgi_stdio.FCGI_printf
  (Interfaces.C.Strings.New_String ("Content-Type: text/plain" 
                                    & ASCII.LF & ASCII.LF));
```

[edited 13.1.13]

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it! But the errors are still the same.

Comment: May I ask, how do you program on your Mac? How you got the information that it crashed on line va_start(ap, format);?

Comment: I use Emacs, and usually build from the command line. I wrote this up [on my blog](http://forward-in-code.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/tracking-down-programerror.html). Anyone - what's SO protocol? Should I have edited the answer here?